# Get word occurrences

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to get the number of occurrences of each word in a csv file with r.
My dataset looks like this:

```
                                        TITLE
1                                       My first Android app after a year
2                                 Unmanned drone buzzes French police car
3                                       Make anything editable with HTML5
4                                          Predictive vs Reactive control
5 What was it like to move to San Antonio and go through TechStars Cloud?
6               Health-care sector vulnerable to hackers, researchers say
```

And I have tried using the funciton used in 'Machine Learning for Hackers':

```
get.tdm <- function(doc.vec) {
            doc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(doc.vec))
            control <- list(stopwords=TRUE, removePunctuation=TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE, minDocFreq=2)
            doc.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(doc.corpus, control) 
            return(doc.dtm)
}
```

But I get an error I dont understand:

```
Error: is.Source(s) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In is.Source(s) : vectorized sources must have a positive length entry
```

What could possibly the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should try it as a `DataframeSource` rather than a `VectorSource`: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tm/docs/DataframeSource

Comment: I now get this:

In is.Source(s) : invalid length entry denoting the number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (calling your dataframe `df`)

```
library(tm)
doc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df))
freq <- data.frame(count=termFreq(doc.corpus[[1]]))
freq
#             count
# after           1
# and             1
# android         1
# antonio         1
# anything        1
# ...
# unmanned        1
# vulnerable      1
# was             1
# what            1
# with            1
# year            1
```

Comment: this work to count the number of occurences of each words for the first line, is there a way to adapt it to count the number of each word in the whole set?

Comment: Sorry. You need to use `df`, not `df$TITLE` in the first line. See my edits.